# Passing both action method names and parameters as arguments to facelets componenets

Tags: jsf, facelets, composite-component

I know passing the method name as a parameter name should be done in this way:

```
itemBean="#{bean}"
itemAction="someMethod"
```

in the component:

```
action="#{itemBean[itemAction]}"
```

and I also know that I can pass the parameters if method name is not a variable ,for ex for the display method, like:

```
parameter = "Hello World"
```

in the component:

```
action="#{itembean.display( parameter )}"
```

But I cannot do them both at the same time

I thought the expression `action="#{itemBean[method](parameter)}"` will do the job but it gives a parsig error.

Any ideas?